# WFFM: What happens when we delete a wffm form?

Tags: wffm, mongodb

I am using Sitecore 8.1 with WFFM. And i am new to WFFM. I found that when user enters data to WFFM forms it will get stored in MongoDB formdata collection. What will happen if the WFFM form will get deleted from CMS?. Will it remove the data from MongoDB also?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you delete a form enter data is not deleted from Mongo.

In Sitecore 7, we were able to delete the responses for each webform from the Report tab.
However, there is no such option available in Sitecore 8. Opening the tab (Detailed Reports) displayes an overview of all entered data in the form.

This functionality was removed in WFFM 2.5 (Data tab has been removed from the Form Reports application. Users can use the export functionality to export an XML or Excel file for handling detailed individual data.)

Please see release notes: https://sdn.sitecore.net/products/web%20forms%20for%20marketers/web%20forms%20for%20marketers%202,-d-,5/release%20notes.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Sitecore Climber. I have one more question. We are having multi-site, do you know where those formdata with site information stored in MongoDB?. I could see only the FormID and its information. Where we can find the site information of that FormData.?

Comment: @Ramesh please open another question for that

Comment: @Richard Created another question :https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6113/wffm-how-multisite-formdata-get-saved-in-mongodb